# Caesar: Checking the key

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am trying to check the key of the cipher text to see if every character is an integer.
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SbI5.png)
When I compile the program I get the following error
[code compiling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7TB9.png)

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not images. Please read about creating [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and consider reading [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: thanks for that, I will look into to improve.

Comment: You can [edit] your question right now.

Comment: There are lots of questions with the tags [cs50] and [caesar-cipher].  Most of them will show you what you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

You can do as bellow:

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string key);
void print_usage() {
  printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
}

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    print_usage();
    return 1;
  }

  if (!only_digits(argv[1])) {
    print_usage();
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

bool only_digits(string key) {
  int key_length = strlen(key);
  for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++) {
    if (isdigit(key[i]) == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Your problem is:

1. Line 6: only_digits should receive argument type `string`, not `string[1]` (array of string)
2. Line 26, 33: `argv[1]` is the way you access to the 2nd element in `argv` array.
   While `argv[1]` in function prototype `bool only_digits(string argv[1])` is declaring an argument with array type (with 1 element)